# Caching Digest Authentication Responses

Tags: httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am using Apache's HttpClient to talk to a server that requires Digest Authentication.

I set up an HttpClientContext with credentials like so:

```
@Bean
public HttpClientContext getCredentialsHttpClientContext() {
    HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
    context.setCredentialsProvider(createCredentialsProvider());
    context.setAuthCache(new BasicAuthCache());
    return context;
}
```

Later on I use this context to stream data from my server:

```
public InputStream getInputStreamFromUrl(String url) throws IOException {
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(new HttpGet(url), clientContext);
    return httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
}
```

Later on in processing this input stream, I need to make calls to the same server using the HttpClientContext, and every subsequent call requires authentication.

Is it possible to cache the results of the digest auth, so that subsequent requests don't need to be authenticated again?

Comment: HttpClient caches Digest and Basic auth state by default. As long as one uses the same HTTP context for logically related requests Digest auth state should be shared (re-used) by all requests.

Comment: You should be using CloseableHttpClient as a singleton bean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@oleg's comments above pointed me in the right direction.

I actually create a singleton HttoClientContext bean:

```
@Bean
public HttpClientContext getCredentialsHttpClientContext() {
    HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
    context.setCredentialsProvider(createCredentialsProvider());
    context.setAuthCache(new BasicAuthCache());
    return context;
}
```

I inject this into a service that I use in the `getInputStreamFromUrl` method above.

In other cases, I am using the `RestOperations` template. In order for this to work, I created the following Spring bean, creates a `RestTemplate` using the same HttpClientContext singelton:

```
@Bean
public RestOperations getIcsCredentialedRestOperations() {
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactoryWithContext(httpClient, httpClientContext);
    return new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
}
```

In the above example, HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory extends HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory overriding the `createHttpContext` method returning the context that I want.

Comment: Using HttoClientContext as a singleton is a bad idea. While the class itself is threading safe, it may contain attributes that are not. Please consider making AuthCache and CredentialsProvider singletons but HttoClientContext needs to be a prototype bean. It needs to be created on a per thread basis

Comment: Thanks!  I've fixed this, by constructing the HttpClientContext when I need it.